# Extracting data with all fields from a postgresql database and creating a new model with some new fields in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
'NAME': '*****',
'USER': '******',
'PASSWORD': '*****',
'HOST': '******',
'PORT': '***',
}
}
```

I am using a postgresql sql database hosted online .The thing is I want to create a new model with all common fields and some additional fields.Can anyone  help me with how should i proceed?.Also im using django-mailbox to import the messages and attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are searching for is `python manage.py inspectdb`, coming from the [django documentation about integrating with legacy databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/).

It will inspect an existing database and create unmanaged models for you that you can use similar to normal models in your application.